# Sorting numbers between x.00 x.99 and so on from database

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

As the title what I'm trying to do is get numbers from database which I already do display them from descending order which I do. Patch numbers are in format X.XX so 2.01 2.05 2.22 and so on I want to label numbers between 2.00 - 2.highest one as Season 2 so Season 2 then patches like 2.99 2.85 2.04 2.00 etc.

My PHP:

```
                foreach($patches as $patch)
                {
                    if(substr($patch, -2)=="00"){
                    echo 'Season '.substr($patch, 0,1).'<br>';}
                    echo '<a href="../index.php?Patch_No='.$patch.'" class="patches">'.$patch.'</a><br/>';

                }
```

And my query:

```
 $patches = $conn->prepare("SELECT Patch_No FROM info ORDER BY Patch_No DESC");
            $patches->execute();
            $patchesresult = $patches->get_result();
            while($data1 = $patchesresult->fetch_assoc()){
                $patch[$i]=$data1["Patch_No"];
                $i+=1;
            }
```

I probably have to check what is currently the highest patch so It could write first title Season XX

UPDATE - my 2D array:

```
$i=$j=0;
                    foreach($patches as $patch)
                    {
                        if($j!=0){
                            if(substr($patch, 0,1)!=substr($patch_array[$i][$j-1],0,1)){
                                $i+=1;
                                $j=0;
                            }
                        }   
                        echo '$patch_array['.$i.']['.$j.'] '.$patch_array[$i][$j]=$patch.' substr$patch='.substr($patch, 0,1).' substr_previous: '.substr($patch_array[$i][$j-1],0,1).'<br/>';
                        $j+=1;
                    }
```

The array saves under [$i][$j] $i - is for patches with the same first number so 2.xx 2.xx 2.xx will be under the same $i and $j are for endings .01 .03 .04 
so 
[0][1] [0][2] [0][3] - {2.50 2.14 2.01} 
[1][1] [1][2] [1][3] - {3.03 3.10 3.02}

Now I need to figure out displaying bit second loop

Comment: which part are you stuck on? look like you're pretty much there... just push the substr($patch, 0,1) to the array, no?

Comment: Well I probably have to make separate loops one foreach that would put patches in 2D array and then second one to display it because now it doesnt know what will be the next number

Comment: yeah, definitely need a 2d array.  I will try to cook it up real quick...

Comment: where are you building your patches array?

Comment: I didn't do the 2D I'm figuring one out right now I'll update the code after I'll get it working

Answer (score 0):

I changed up some syntax and variable names to make it a bit less confusing, but I think this is what you are going for. Also changed (improved) your query syntax.

```
$patches = $conn->prepare("SELECT Patch_No FROM info ORDER BY Patch_No DESC");
$patches->execute();
$patches->bind_result($patchNum);

$episodes=array();

while($patches->fetch_assoc()){            
      //build 1d array
      $data=array($patchNum, substr($patch,0,1));
      //push 1d array to array of arrays (2d array)
      $episodes[]=$data;
      echo '<a href="../index.php?Patch_No='.$patchNum.'" 
               class="patches"
            >'.$patch.'</a><br/>';
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is not always will there be patch 2.00 the smallest possible could be also like 2.01 etc. check my update with new array

Comment: now I need somehow to get the index of last element from each array row so [1][1] [1][2] [1][3] [2][1][2][2][2][3][2][4] I need to get values like 3 and 4 from this I found the 'end' function and trying to incorporate it